# Can I use a low dropout voltage regulator to drop a 5V 100 nSec pulse to 3.3V?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

I am using an analog switch IC with 3.6V as a maximum operating voltage. The input to the analog switch is the output pulse from a multi-vibrator which is 5V and 100nSec width.

I need to drop the vibrator output to less than 3.6V without affecting the pulse width. In this case, can I use an LDO to drop the voltage?

Comment: Saying "without changing the pulse width" makes this virtually impossible to solve. Tell us how much change in pulse width is allowable.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that there must be delay in signal. Maximum I can tolerate 10nSec.

Comment: No, I don't mean that the signal will be delayed. I mean that the pulse width **will change**. How much of a change can you tolerate?

Comment: I can accept 10nSec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regulator is not a good option. Too slow and possibly not stable without capacitors.

You could use a resistive divider, but another option is to use a purpose-designed level translator chip such as the [74LVC1T45](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74LVC1T45.pdf), which can work from 1.65V to 5.5V in either direction. When converting 5V to 3.3 it has a propagation delay of less than 5.4ns over the whole temperature range. It also draws hardly any current normally when not switching.

[image]

Comment: I need 2 bit in a single package  transceiver

Comment: There are other similar products with more channels or use two.

Comment: @krishnamoorthijayakumar While this looks like a good solution to me, you should be aware that the pulse width will be affected. The rise and fall times for this device's outputs are not **exactly** the same. You didn't tell us how much of a change you could tolerate.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well, a 1pF load on a 1.4/3.6K resistive divider will cause about 1ns delay. There's more likely to be 5 or 10pF. A chip like this is about as close to perfect as it gets without extreme measures.

Comment: I agree. I wasn't criticizing your answer, I was trying to make the OP be realistic with their requirements. And the issue isn't the delay, but the fact that the rise and fall times from this level translator are not exactly the same, so the pulse **duration** will change. It's a tiny change, but the OP was unrealistically saying "without affecting the pulse width".

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, can I use LDO to drop the voltage?

No because virtually all (LDO or non LDO) regulators require input and output capacitors and, all voltage regulators are far slower in operation than that needed to main the signal's shape and edge integrity.

Use a resistive potential divider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the output pulse width from the voltage divider?

Comment: Providing you don’t pick silly values for each resistor, the pulse width will be within 1 ns of the original, but, to be sure, I’d need to look at the circuit that is fed this signal. Also, what is this signal used for?

Comment: I need to bypass the analog signal which is ~60nSec. So I drive the analog switch by using a multivibrator.

Answer (score 2):

An LDO would probably not turn on in 100 ns (note standard SI units). Instead you can probably use a voltage divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fohc89.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A voltage divider to convert a 5 V signal to 3.6 V.*

The resistor values were chosen for easy calculation. You can scale up or down but watch out for loading effect of following circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The resistive divider solution so the simplest one. Go ahead with those. If you see loading effects (sagging of signal transition) you can also opt for active clamping using zener diode or BJTs (consider the inverted logic, if it going to MCU it can. be handled, else invert it again..or go with Zener clamping or dedicated level shifter IC) depending on what you have handy.

[image: resistor and zener diode clamp]

<sub>Image source: [Fig. 7, *Resistor and Zener diode* from "How to interface a 5V output to a 3.3V input" on next-hack.com](https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/09/15/how-to-interface-a-5v-output-to-a-3-3v-input/)</sub>

[image: BJT/MOSFET as inverter can be used as level shifter]

<sub>Image source: [Fig. 10, *BJT/MOSFET as inverter can be used as level shifter* from "How to interface a 5V output to a 3.3V input" on next-hack.com](https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/09/15/how-to-interface-a-5v-output-to-a-3-3v-input/)</sub>

Comment: Note that the transistor level shifters invert the signal and they are crude digital inverters. If you have a digital signal going into the 3.3V domain, then just use a digital switch or multiplexer.

Comment: @HorrorVacui updated.

Answer (score 0):

No. LDOs are there to reduce any noise, disturbance on their input and provide a clean and stable output voltage. They are voltage regulators. Their stability also implies that they are slow.

You can use a resistor divider as @transistor suggested, but then you might have other troubles depending on the capacitive load of the switch and on the node on its output. Basically you introduce a series resistance; Your signal source is not an - approximately - ideal voltage source any more, but it will have a series resistance (look up 'Thevenin equivalent circuit'). In the mentioned example it is 1kOhm, which will form a 10MHz low-pass filter with only 16pF, which you can get easily on a PCB if you are not careful. The period of 10MHz is 100ns, which is your pulse width. To compensate the filtering you might add a capacitor in parallel with the upper resistance to cancel the pole. Moreover your signal will be driven with 1kOhm, which means it is more susceptible to capacitive coupling. You can add a unity gain buffer amp after it to alleviate this if it is really a trouble, but it is an extra component with additional power consumption.

In general I would use components which all can withstand the supply voltage of the system, or the other way around: choose a supply voltage where all of your components are safe. There are way too much trouble in supply domain crossing, and very often it can be avoided. Most of the analog ICs even nowadays works with 5V. The exceptions are really high speed circuits, but the 100ns pulse is - arguable though - not extremely fast.

Why analog switch? Isn't it a digital signal? There are digital level translators. A signal pulse seems to me a digital signal. If this is the case, just pick a digital level translator. They are failsafe, do not burn any static current and they drive their outputs properly. I am really confused by the description of using an analog switch for a digital pulse. If the signal source is digital, then you do not need an analog switch.

Comment: the digital pulse from the vibrator is used to control the switch. Here I am using an analog switch to bypass analog signal.

Comment: OK. So its the control signal of the switch. Either 1) use a 5V input tolerant analog switch or 2) add a digital level translator before the switch control input.