# Need suggestion on 2 channel transceiver 5V to 3.3V level shifter

Tags: level-shifting, transceiver

I need to Interface multivibrator output to control input of the analog switch. Where the maximum operating voltage of analog switch is 3.6V. So I need voltage level shifter from 5V to 3.3V. And the output of the Multivibrator is a timing data so I need a transceiver 5V to 3.3V without affecting the pulse width(I can accept ~15nSec tolerance)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480187/can-i-use-a-low-dropout-voltage-regulator-to-drop-a-5v-100-nsec-pulse-to-3-3v/480193#480193 had you any troubles with these solutions?

Comment: I can't find a suitable IC for my work. I need 2 channel IC. In particular, it is very hard to find adapters to convert it to DIP package

Comment: Any reason why you want to use an IC instead of some resistors, mosfets and/or zenerdiodes?

Comment: The pulse width should remain the same because that was timing data. I tried with resistors but they affect the pulse width.@David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the job:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lsf0102.pdf

It was straight forward to find one. But, whether it is perfect foryour application or not, you have to decide. Price, Space, sourcing etc

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have found this IC SN74AHC125N, Which has 4 channels. The main advantage is this IC available in DIP package

Comment: @krishnamoorthijayakumar, The problem statement didn't say that DIP package is preferred. Please edit your question post to include all the requirements needed to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Also, SN74AHC125 has specs that say it won't be damaged by 5 V inputs, but that use for level translation isn't recommended (low levels might not register correctly when used in your application).

Comment: @ThePhoton The AHC125 (or any other buffer with overvoltage-tolerant inputs) works fine for downtranslation. As far as I can see, a transceiver is not required.

Comment: @CL., see section 9.2.1 of the [SN74AHC125N datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc125.pdf). They are not recommending using this part for level translation. Other parts like SN74LVC125 have specs that are better for level translation applications (but SN74LVC125 is not available in DIP).

Comment: @ThePhoton The maximum low level is 0.9 V, which is more than enough for this application.